# Views disappear when `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` set `NO`

Tags: ios, autolayout

### Problem

Some third party library is used. Some views disappear after their `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` are set to `NO`.

Don't have other `autoresizingMask` setting for my views in my own code; in the library, the `autoresizingMask` parts of code have been removed too. Instead, explicit bounds/center/frame are set for those views. There're no nib files, views are all programmatically created.

I know some other people solve similar problem by giving a thorough autolayout constraints set, but in my case, I mean to turn off autolayout and do it manually. No idea when autolayout is turned on.

Some people say that "by default, as your app launches, autolayout is switched off, and the system behaves as in iOS 5 and before. But if, at any time while your app runs, the system sees an autolayout constraint (generated in code or by the loading of a nib that has “Use autolayout” checked), the autolayout system is switched on, and from then on you’re running under autolayout." (Programming iOS 6 by Matt Neuberg, pages 383-384), but in my project I don't think there's any autolayout constraints left.

The code is bulky, but will upload some skeleton if necessary.

Thank you for tips!

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use Auto Layout you have to set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `YES`. Here's [a reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/AutolayoutPG/AdoptingAutoLayout/AdoptingAutoLayout.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH15-SW1):

> This works through the property
>   translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints. When this property is YES,
>   which it is by default, the autoresizing mask of a view is translated
>   into constraints. For example, if a view is configured as in Figure
>   6-1 and translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints is YES, then the
>   constraints |-20-[button]-20-| and V:|-20-[button(20)] are added to
>   the view’s superview. The net effect is that unaware views behave as
>   they did in versions of OS X prior to 10.7.
>
> For views that are aware of Auto Layout, in most circumstances you
>   will want translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints to be NO. This is
>   because the constraints generated by translating the autoresizing mask
>   are already sufficient to completely specify the frame of a view given
>   its superview’s frame, which is generally too much. For example, this
>   will prevent a button from automatically assuming its optimal width
>   when its title is changed.

Comment: The reference link expires, @ArkadiuszHolko, can you renew it?

Comment: @congliu: Fixed. Apple must have changed it yesterday.

Comment: Hi @ArkadiuszHolko, why we have to set translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints to YES when not using Auto Layout? In my understanding, because we don't use Auto Layout, then then we don't need any constraints. So we don't need to set translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints to YES.

Comment: @congliu: From what I understood at the time you tried to disable Auto Layout by setting `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `NO`, where you should use `YES`. `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` is set to `YES` by default, so you generally don't have to set it explicitly.