# MKMapView show blank on annotation selection iOS8

Tags: ios, mkmapview, ios8, xcode6, mkannotation

I have face some strange behaviour of MKMapview in iOS 8.
I have custom view (subclass of UIView) which contain MKMapview in it.

`NMView -> MKMapView`

**NMView Code**

```
#import "NMView.h"

@implementation NMView

@synthesize mapView;
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        frame=self.bounds;
        self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=NO;
        mapView=[[MKMapView alloc]initWithFrame:frame];
        mapView.showsUserLocation=YES;
        [mapView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight];
        [self setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight];
        mapView.delegate=self;
        [self addSubview:mapView];
        self.backgroundColor=[UIColor grayColor];
    }
    return self;
}
-(void)addCustomAnnotaion:(id<MKAnnotation>)annot{
  MKCoordinateRegion region=MKCoordinateRegionMake(annot.coordinate, MKCoordinateSpanMake(10.0f, 10.0f));
   [mapView setRegion:region];
    [mapView addAnnotation:annot];
   // [mapView selectAnnotation:annot animated:YES];
}

- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapViews viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{

    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]]){
        return nil;
    }
    static NSString * const identifier = @"MyCustomAnnotation";
    MKAnnotationView* annotationView = (MKAnnotationView*)[mapViews dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:identifier];

    if (annotationView){
        annotationView.annotation = annotation;
    }
    else{
        annotationView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:identifier];
        annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;
        UIView *rightView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 0, 80,50)];
        rightView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];

        UIButton* edit = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [edit setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"editPOI"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [edit addTarget:self action:@selector(editPoi:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        edit.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
        edit.frame=CGRectMake(15, 5, 30,30);

        UIButton* delButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [delButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"deletePOI"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [delButton addTarget:self action:@selector(deletePoi:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        delButton.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
        delButton.frame=CGRectMake(55, 5, 30,30);

        [rightView addSubview:delButton];
        [rightView addSubview:edit];

        UIImageView *imgviewIcon=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)];
        [imgviewIcon setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pin.png"]];
        [annotationView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pin.png"]];
        [annotationView layoutIfNeeded];
        annotationView.leftCalloutAccessoryView=imgviewIcon;
        annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView=rightView;

    }

    return annotationView;

}
-(IBAction)editPoi:(id)sender{
    //edit
}
-(IBAction)deletePoi:(id)sender{
    //delete
}
```

I am adding NMView to my view controller

```
NMView *nv=[[NMView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, 300, 400)];
[self.view addSubview:nv];
```

Now i am adding annotation to mapview using custom method of NMView,

```
MKPointAnnotation *point=[[MKPointAnnotation alloc]init];
point.coordinate=pinCoordinate;
point.title=@"test";
[nv addCustomAnnotaion:point];
```

I have tested it in iOS7 in its working fine:

[image]

But in **iOS8** on selection of annotation whole **NMView goes blank**.

Is it bug of iOS 8 or i am doing something wrong ??
Please Help..

**EDIT**

If i select annotation programatically then also same problem occur in iOS 8.

`[mapView selectAnnotation:annot animated:YES];`

Somebody else base face this issue ??

iOS8 Blank screen.
:
[image]

I have uploaded project at below url:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxkVP7smm8Z6SnM1UjBxcjc5aDg/view?usp=sharing

Please check it let me know..

Comment: Irrelevant to your problem but if you don't set your annotation view's `centerOffset` it will show wrong point when you zoom out, the English channel in your case.

Comment: @Desdenova:thanks for reply, but right now thats not problem, main problem is mkmapview goes blank on annotation selection.

Comment: See my anser under http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14707080/after-json-parsing-viewforannotation-shows-only-one-single-annotation-on-mkmapv/32965056#32965056 Hope that helps somebody too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure why, but it works if you delete this line :

```
self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=NO;
```

Reference: 
[Views disappear when `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` set `NO`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19627825/views-disappear-when-translatesautoresizingmaskintoconstraints-set-no)

Comment: Thanks for reply,It works as you said , but i want to know reason, it is not happening in iOS 7, can you tell me..

Comment: @user3057005 I'd be happy to explain if I could ... I guess it depends on the new size classes in iOS 8 or might be a bug, no clue. Here is a more detailed post about combining the two approaches, maybe it helps you : http://objectivetoast.com/2014/06/02/translating-autoresizing-masks-into-constraints/

Answer (score 0):

This is not the complete solution, but a step towards diagnosing the problem.

1- Added the following to the NMView class

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view {

    NSLog(@"MapView: %@", mapView);

    //so that I can check the view hierarchy after the user taps on the annotation view
    [self performSelector:@selector(viewHierarchy) withObject:nil afterDelay:5];
}

- (void) viewHierarchy {

    NSLog(@"Self: %@", self); //set a break point here
    //inspect the view hierarchy by typing 'po [self recursiveDescription]' in the debugger 

}
```

Output from '[po recursiveDescription]'. Look at the frame of NMView  "frame = **(-65 -113; 0 0)**", likely an auto layout issue.

NMView: 0x7fa63bc95390; frame = **(-65 -113; 0 0)**; autoresize = W+H; layer = >
   | >
   |    | ; layer = >
   |    |    | >
   |    |    |    | <_MKMapLayerHostingView: 0x7fa63bc9b0e0; frame = (0 0; 0 0); layer = <_MKMapLayerHostingLayer: 0x7fa63bc9bfe0>>
   |    |    |    |    |  (layer)
   |    |    |    |    |    |  (layer)
   |    |    | >
   |    |    | >
   |    |    |    | >
   |    |    |    |    | >
   |    |    |    |    |    | <_MKPopoverEmbeddingView: 0x7fa63ef600f0; frame = (149.5 155; 0 0); layer = >
   |    |    |    |    |    |    | <_UIPopoverView: 0x7fa63ef1e4e0; frame = (-84.5 -57; 170 57); layer = >
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | >
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | >
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <_MKCalloutBackgroundMaskView: 0x7fa63ef1f4e0; frame = (0 0; 170 57); layer = >
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | >
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | >
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | >
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | >
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | >
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | >
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | >
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <_MKSmallCalloutPassthroughButton: 0x7fa63ef60900; baseClass = UIControl; frame = (0 0; 170 57); layer = >
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <_MKCalloutAccessoryWrapperView: 0x7fa63d9f8c10; frame = (90 0; 80 50); clipsToBounds = YES; layer = >
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | >
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | >
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | >
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | >
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | >
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <_MKSmallCalloutContainerView: 0x7fa63bcc4aa0; frame = (0 0; 170 44); clipsToBounds = YES; layer = >
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <_MKCalloutAccessoryWrapperView: 0x7fa63dc6d890; frame = (7 7; 30 30); clipsToBounds = YES; layer = >
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | >
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | >
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | >
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | >
   |    | >

Comment: Thnks for reply , can you suggest the solution?